# How bad is it to have a telelens without VR?

Tags: telephoto, image-stabilization

Yesterday I bought an AF-P Nikkor 70-300 and it was supposed to have VR but today the package arrived and I realized that it does not have it. Sincerily, it bothers me some to ask my money back so I was wondering if it is too bad to keep it like that. I mean, is it too hard to take good photos without a tripode and without VR? I want to use it for wild life photography.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: If the item wasn't as described, you should ask for at least a partial refund.

Comment: I disagree with @xiota. I would go further. Aside from any conversation about wildlife photography without image stabilisation, if the item was advertised as having VR and ultimately doesn't have it, you should return it for a full refund. Absolutely. And use a more reputable/knowledgeable retailer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that, for a non-vr lens, a photographer of average skill can take a stable image at a shutter speed of 1/{focal length}.

So at full zoom, 1/300 of a second shutter speed is the slowest you can go unless your hands are uncommonly stead. Depending on the model year, the VR version of that lens compensates for 4-4.5 stops of camera shake. Realistically, you're probably looking at less at full extension, but 1/60 should be possible for an average photographer.

Assuming you paid for the VR and they sent you the wrong one, send it back. Otherwise, no, a VR lens is not strictly necessary, but for the kind of shooting you want to do, it does have significant value.

You could also poke around the used department at some of the bigger camera suppliers, you can frequently find a late model Nikkor 80-400 VR in very good condition at about the same price point.

Comment: Another advantage of VR (at least the optical kind: Nikon/Canon) is that it stabilizes the viewfinder and therefore what is on the focus points.